# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : for a valid JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get a cross-domain JSON data via $.ajax method

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: "http://nrb.org.np/exportForexJSON.php?YY=2016&MM=06",
      crossDomain : true,
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        console.log("done");
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
        // alert(xhr.responseText);
        // alert(textStatus);
    });
```

The JSON returned by the url is

```
{
    "Conversion": {
        "Currency": [{
            "Date": "2016-06-23",
            "BaseCurrency": "INR",
            "TargetCurrency": "NPR",
            "BaseValue": "100",
            "TargetBuy": "160.00",
            "TargetSell": "160.15"
        }, {
            "Date": "2016-06-23",
            "BaseCurrency": "USD",
            "TargetCurrency": "NPR",
            "BaseValue": "1",
            "TargetBuy": "107.76",
            "TargetSell": "108.36"
        }, {
            "Date": "2016-06-23",
            "BaseCurrency": "BHD",
            "TargetCurrency": "NPR",
            "BaseValue": "1",
            "TargetBuy": "285.75",
            "TargetSell": "N/A"
        }]
    }
}
```

I checked if the JSON is valid by using http://jsonlint.com/. The JSON is Okay. I get a console error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The console is pointing to the error in the following screenshot

[image]

Comment: I don't think we can use POST with `jsonp`. Just use GET.

Comment: you can't use that api with js, but you can use YQL to turn the JSON into JSONP

Comment: @dandavis If I dont use jsonp, it wouldn't be a cross-domain request. It would throw this error.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21506127/3639582)** might help.

Comment: JSONP needs to be implimented by the server, just like CORS. i'm afraid you need to proxy or use YQL if you want your users to be able to grab that data

Comment: If you are already getting a JSON in response, I'd suggest you read this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13022566/3437508

Comment: JSON.stringify(data) and console that..you will not get that error

Comment: JSON.Parse(data) will throw that unexpected token : error and if you JSON.stringify ,  it will covert that value to JSON string

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GqNwBG

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `dataType` to `"json"`

Answer (score 0):

Responses with javascript content-type are evaluated automatically.
JavaScript JSON parser treats { and } as a block instead of object.

Set correct Content-Type header for the JSON file.
OR save it with .json extension.

Your url has **.json** extension while header is **jsonp**
, Try making it same

Not quite sure of POST and JSONP
: [Post data to JsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp)